# hw_timer_t, timerAttachInterrupt, portENTER_CRITICAL etc... not defined for ESP8266

Tags: timer, esp8266, isr

I have an ESP8266 NodeMCU 12E development board.  I'm trying to implement an ISR that uses a hardware timer as described by [this blog here](https://techtutorialsx.com/2017/10/07/esp32-arduino-timer-interrupts/).  The blog post was originally meant for ESP32 and it provides this final demonstration code which I can not get to compile within Arduino IDE for ESP8266.

```
volatile int interruptCounter;
int totalInterruptCounter;

hw_timer_t * timer = NULL;
portMUX_TYPE timerMux = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;

void IRAM_ATTR onTimer() {
  portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);
  interruptCounter++;
  portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);

}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  timer = timerBegin(0, 80, true);
  timerAttachInterrupt(timer, &onTimer, true);
  timerAlarmWrite(timer, 1000000, true);
  timerAlarmEnable(timer);

}

void loop() {

  if (interruptCounter > 0) {

    portENTER_CRITICAL(&timerMux);
    interruptCounter--;
    portEXIT_CRITICAL(&timerMux);

    totalInterruptCounter++;

    Serial.print("An interrupt as occurred. Total number: ");
    Serial.println(totalInterruptCounter);

  }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the errors that say hw_timer_t, portENTER_CRITICAL, portEXIT_CRITICAL, timerAttachInterrupt, timerAlarmWrite, etc... all don't exist.

Am I supposed to import some library to support this demonstration code?

I can't seem to find talks of hardware timer for ESP8266.  Every one seems to talk about hardware timer for ESP32 instead.

Answer (score 1):

They're not defined because they're in the ESP32 SDK, which is completely separate (different CPU, different instruction set, different OS) from the ESP8266. Documentation about the ESP32 won't apply to the ESP8266.

Take a look at the [ESP8266 "NONOS SDK"](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_NONOS_SDK) - this is the "OS" that the ESP8266 Arduino SDK is built on. It includes calls for hardware timers (`hw_timer_init()`, `hw_timer_arm()`, `hw_timer_set_func()`). You can find the documentation for it [here](http://file:///Users/romkey/Downloads/2c-esp8266_non_os_sdk_api_reference_en.pdf).

Beware, there's also a "Free RTOS" for the ESP8266. When you're searching for example code, people are often not clear about whether their code is for the NONOS SDK or the Free RTOS SDK.

Free RTOS a separate piece of software; you won't be able to use its functions in an Arduino SDK program. Some people have gotten parts of the Arduino SDK running with it but that's a deep rabbit hole that can waste a lot of your time. If you decide to go that route you're better off abandoning the Arduino SDK calls and just writing a proper FreeRTOS program.

Comment: In my `C:\Users\john\Documents\ArduinoData\library.json` file, I see reference to a `http://downloads.arduino.cc/libraries/github.com/feilipu/FreeRTOS-10.0.0-1.zip`.  I do not see reference to a NONOS SDK in that file.  Also my compiler complains about `hw_timer_init(),FRC1_SOURCE etc...` not being defined.  Do you think this means my board is a FreeRTOS?   Is it easy to switch over to the nonos SDK one?

Comment: No, that's for Arduinos, not the ESP8266. The NONOS-SDK isn't a separate library, you don't need to download it and it wouldn't be listed in library.json. The ESP8266 Arduino framework is based on it. You are not using Free RTOS.

Comment: oh ok. At the moment, I still get errors that hw_timer_init(), FRC1_SOURCE etc... are not declared or defined when I try to compile within the Arduino IDE.  I can't seem to find any mention on the internet of others encountering the same issue. Do you know how I can resolve this issue? Thanks